# Need help creating Grails executeQuery based on domain and lookup table

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I have two classes: sample, and parameter. I also have a sample_sample_parameter lookup table which exists to hold the sample id and the parameter id. This is mapped in my grails app.

I was able to write an sql query that works in squirrel:

```
select s.* from sample s, sample_sample_parameters sp where s.id = sp.sample_id and sp.sample_parameter_id = 41
```

where 41 would be replaced with the parameter.id variable passed from the gsp page to the action. I have also tried to make it work with executeQuery but it tells me that sample is not mapped.

How do I turn this query into a gorm recognizable form?

```
class Sample {


Date collectionDate // date the sample was collected
Date sampleReceivedDate // date the sample arrived on site
Date dateCreated
String sampleComments // details about the sample
String labAccessionID // internal reference
String sampleGender // is it from a male or female?
String sampleAge // the age of the animal the sample was taken from
String sampleBreed // the breed of animal
String sampleNameID // patient name
String filepath

String enteredby


String sg
String mosm

static searchable = true


static hasMany =[sampleParameters:SampleParameter, ficsruns:Ficsrun]//[tags:Tag]// a Sample can have many parameters
/* mappedBy allows two tables share a common table. It creates two join tables, one for each. 
 * SampleParameter is the table being shared by Sample and SampleType tables */
static mappedBy=[sampleParameters:"samples"]//[tags:"domainClass1s"]/*http://www.van-porten.de/2010/09/multiple-many-to-many-in-grails/*/
static belongsTo = [sampleType:SampleType, labFinding:LabFinding, sampleSource:SampleSource, species:SpeciesList] // creates dependencies


static constraints = {

    sampleType(blank:false)
    sampleNameID(blank:false)
    collectionDate(blank:false)
    sampleReceivedDate(blank:false)
    sampleComments(nullable:true, maxSize:1000)
    labAccessionID(nullable:true)
    sampleGender(blank:false, inList:["M","F","NM","SF", "UNK"])
    sampleAge(nullable: true)
    sampleBreed(nullable:true)
    sampleSource(blank:false)
    species(blank:false)
    labFinding(nullable:true)
    filepath(nullable:true)
    enteredby(nullable:true)
    sg(nullable:true)
    mosm(nullable:true)
    dateCreated()
}

/* This section is for static mapping to the hematology database*/
   static mapping = {
    version false
    id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'SHARED_SEQ']   
   }

   String toString(){
    "${sampleNameID}"
  }
}


class SampleParameter implements Comparable{


String name
String value

static hasMany = [
samples:Sample,         //domainClass1s: DomainClass1,
sampleTypes:SampleType  //domainClass2s: DomainClass2
]
static mapping = {
    version false
    id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'SHARED_SEQ']   
}

  static mappedBy =        [samples:"sampleParameters",sampleTypes:"sampleParameters"]//[domainClass1s: "tags", domainClass2s: "tags"]
  static belongsTo =[Sample,SampleType] //[DomainClass1, DomainClass2]

  static constraints = {
     name(blank:false)
     //value()
     //value(unique:true)
     value (unique: 'name')
 }

@Override public String toString() {
return name + " " + value
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (o == null || this == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return value.compareTo(o.value)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you pls paste the code of your domain classes? You say there is `Sample` and there is `Paramter`. Does the Sample-class have a property `Parameter param`? Is there a third class?

Comment: When you use executeQuery, how is your hql query specifically?

Comment: `def allParameters = Sample.executeQuery("select s.sample from sample s, sample_sample_parameters sp where s.id = sp.sample_id and sp.sample_parameter_id = 41")` where 41 needs to be a ${VARIABLE}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first suggestion, when you have the paramter's id, do the following.

```
Parameter p = Parameter.get(params.id) // or wherever your id is stored
List<Sample> samples = Sample.findAllByParameter(p) // this assumes, the parameter property is actually named 'parameter'
```

Of course there is no error handling in place right now, but you'll get the idea.

Welcome to GORM, welcome to Grails.

Comment: I tried this and now am getting an error Message: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1 any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not using a HQL query in your executeQuery method. Instead you're using native sql. From the manual:

> The executeQuery method allows the execution of arbitrary HQL queries.

Take a look at the [specification](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) to see ways of doing that. Which, by the way, are way easier than native sql.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the specification previously, but it doesn't have an example of how to return results based on a join or lookup table.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought your problem was your object Sample couldn't be mapped, since its name was lower case.

Comment: By the way, you can find how to use hql joins in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Comment: I see. I tried capitalization of the domain but it still says it is not mapped. ` def allParameters = Sample.executeQuery("select s.sample from SAMPLE s, SAMPLE_SAMPLE_PARAMETERS sp where s.id = sp.sample_id and sp.sample_parameter_id = 41")` Message: SAMPLE is not mapped [select s.sample from SAMPLE s, SAMPLE_SAMPLE_PARAMETERS sp where s.id = sp.sample_id and sp.sample_parameter_id = 41]

Comment: That's not what I meant. Sorry. If you look at the example in the link I mentioned, you'll notice that you should not use the name of the table, but the name of your class (Sample in this case). Also, in HQL you don't type the join table itself, but the attribute that is referred to make the association.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Sample> samples = Sample.findAllBySampleParameter(SampleParameter.get(variable))
```

Give it a try?

Comment: I try this and it gives me this error: No property found for name [sampleParameter] for class [class lims.Sample]. Stacktrace follows: Message: No property found for name [sampleParameter] for class [class lims.Sample] - SampleParameter has to belong to both Sample and SampleType

Comment: I am not sure if I phrased my question wrong, but what I needed was to find samples that contain a particular dynamic variable. I think I can get to sample via parameter, but cannot get to parameter via sample. Thus I found out that simply using `p.samples` will give me a list of all samples associated with a particular parameter. I was having issues because I was trying it from the sample side, instead of the parameter side.